# How to return to the class from a jframe in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to netbeans. Below is my scenario :

I have created a normal java file in which I'm calling a jframe. jframe have a textbox and submit button.
What I want is that after calling the jframe from the java file, jframe opens up. Then after typing the text in the textbox, when we click on the submit button I should return back to that java file (to the line after I called the jframe) with the text typed. So, that I can use that text in my java file further.

But what is happening now is that when I call the jframe with the below command, jframe opens up and after that rest of the code in the java file gets executed. The java is not waiting for the jframe to return the data.

```
new Frame1(new javax.swing.JFrame(), false).setVisible(true);
```

And below is the code in jframe. But don't know how to return it and use it in java file

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    String s1 = jTextField1.getText();
    argA[0] = s1;
}
```

So, please let me know how can I do it ?

Thanks to all in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Make two methods,

first one be a main method which create the frame.

second one do the things when Jframe done its work.

---

and the case

```
String s1 = jTextField1.getText();
argA[0] = s1;
```

just write

```
argA[0] = jTextField1.getText();
```

make argA as a instance variable then you can call it without to return things.

OR

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
to
private String jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    return YourStringHere;
}
```

By the way, by use netbeans, coding via GUI design mode is more easier to learn.